# Splitting Date from DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

I need help on splitting the date from the below image file.
Please help me to extract date alone.
[image]

I had call this value in my grid view as..

```
date = c.transactionDate,
```

in my grid if i select today's date it display yesterday date..
[image]

My break Line display..
[image]

My Server Response date is correct..
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the online documentation? [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Comment: There are so many options, get Month, Date, Year, Day etc, for date you can use c.transactionDate.Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the Date part from the DateTIme object using `Date` property.

```
string datePart = c.transactionDate.Date.ToString();
```

If you want to show this value in your gridview column then you don't need to do this. You can directly use the `DataFormatString` property

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="TransactionDateField" HeaderText="Transaction Date" DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy}"  />
```

**Edit:**

Your server date and the date which is displaying in the code both are same. As I guess your development machine is in `IST time zone (+05:30)` and the server is returning the time in time zone which is `+11:00`. So there is a difference of `05:30` hours in both time zone.

So when you see the time `2014-02-14T00:00:00:0+1100` in your code (VS). It gets converted into local time zone and display the value accordingly.

So above time zone gets subtracted by `-05:30` hours to get in current time zone (IST) which is equivalent to `13:02-2014:06:30:00 PM`

Comment: @farokemoahmed if you want to show the value same as server's time then you need to change it to server's timezone. that's it..:)

Comment: is possible to make my time 13:02-2014:06:30:00 PM as  00:00:00 and display it.. i should try it without changing the time settings..

Comment: If you just want to display the time in that format and don't want to manipulate the value then you can use the `DataFormatString` in gridview. I have describe it in my post.

Comment: can you please send me an example..?

Answer (score 4):

There is no dedicate pure Date class because you already have DateTime which can handle it. Having Date would lead to duplication and confusion.

use the `Date` property

```
c.transactionDate.Date
```

if you want to show  the date only just do something like this

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;

 var pureDateOnly =  date.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: +1. Just a consideration: I think it would just lead to save some bytes per each value you store. E.g. If I need to store daily values it would be either a waste of space (storing 00:00:00) or, if converted to DateString, inconvenient because you wouldn't be able anymore to properly query your data. Probably it's the reason why sqlserver 2008 introduced date format